# Ionic storage - fetching data gives me [object Object]

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-storage

I'm storing a JSON Array via Ionic Storage like this:

```
this.storage.set('data', this.data).then().catch(err => {
  this.data.splice(this.data.indexOf(Data), 1);
});
```

and fetching it in a function:

```
fetchData(){
    this.storage.get('data').then(
      (data: {value: string, usage: string, date: string, addedDate: string}[]) => {
        this.data = data != null ? data : [];
        console.log('DATA FETCHED: ' + data);
        return data;
      }
    ).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

I stored 4 objects in the array, but the console.log just gives me this back:

```
DATA FETCHED: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

What should I do to get the array displayed right? I already tried with .toString() and .slice()

relevant part in home.html:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
    <h2>{{ item.usage }}</h2>
    <p>{{ item.date | date:'dd MMM yyyy' }}</p>
    <h1 item-end ngClass="{{ item.value.charAt(0) === '-' ? 'expense' : 'income' }}">{{ item.value }} €</h1>
    <!--<h1 item-end class="income">+ 450,00 €</h1>!-->
</ion-item>
```

home.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  items: any = this.moneyService.fetchData();

  incomeval: any = IncomevalPage;
  expenseval: any = ExpensevalPage;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private moneyService: MoneyService) {}

  ionViewWillEnter(){
    this.items = this.moneyService.fetchData();
  }
}
```

Comment: Try changing the log statement to `console.log('DATA FETCHED:', data);`. It will be easier to understand what's going on without everything being casted to string.

Comment: @AndréLaszlo This gives me the correct array objects, but it still doesn't display in the app

Comment: Ok, sounds good. Can you also please share the template and maybe other relevant parts of the component/app?

Comment: @AndréLaszlo I have added the code in the question

Comment: In which class is `fetchData()` located?

Comment: @AndréLaszlo It's located as a function of the MoneyService

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that, in addition to what Marco said in his answer, the problem is that you're not returning anything from `fetchData()`. The return statement is inside the promise. Promises might take a while to get used to, but if you return the result, it will be a new promise with the new value. It might be easier to understand with an example:

```
var promise = Promise.resolve("first").then(val => "second");
promise.then(val => console.log("val is", val));
// Prints: "val is second"
```

You are setting `this.data` of the `MoneyService` but it's not accessed anywhere in the `HomePage` component.

What if you change `fetchData` to this:

```
fetchData(){
  return this.storage.get('data').then((data: {value: string, usage: string, date: string, addedDate: string}[]) => {
    return data != null ? data : [];
  });
}
```

It will now return a promise, which you will have to take care of properly in `HomePage`, maybe something like this (untested):

```
@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
    items: any;

    incomeval: any = IncomevalPage;
    expenseval: any = ExpensevalPage;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private moneyService: MoneyService) {
        moneyService.fetchData().then(result => this.items = result);
    }
}
```

It will update `this.items` as soon as the data is available.

Answer (score 0):

You need some corrections with `home.ts`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  items: any;
  moneyService: any;

  incomeval: any = IncomevalPage;
  expenseval: any = ExpensevalPage;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, data: MoneyService) {
    this.items = null;
    this.moneyService = data;
  }

  ionViewWillEnter(){
    this.items = this.moneyService.fetchData();
  }
}
```

Comment: Still fetches the data but does not display it